# How to define getter and setter properties in a subclass

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have the following code for inheritance:

```
SubClass= function () {
    ParentClass.call(this);
}
SubClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype);
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;
```

However, I want to define some properties in the subclass as well:

```
SubClass.prototype = {

    get x() {
        return this.newX;
    },
    set x(val) {
        this.newX = val;
        alert("X has a value of " + this.newX);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is combining the two. In other words, in the first code sample I'm saying:

```
SubClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype);
```

But then in the second code sample I'm saying:

```
SubClass.prototype = {...
```

How can I achieve both? What is the syntax that would allow me to inherit from a parent class and define properties using the same prototype definition?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Define your properties by passing a property descriptor to `Object.defineProperty`:

```
Object.defineProperty(SubClass.prototype, 'x', {
    configurable: true,
    get: function () {
        return this.newX;
    },
    set: function (val) {
        this.newX = val;
        alert("X has a value of " + this.newX);
    },
});
```

It’s also possible to pass an object containing property descriptors to `Object.create`:

```
function SubClass() {
    ParentClass.call(this);
}

SubClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        configurable: true,
        writable: true,
        value: SubClass,
    },
    x: {
        configurable: true,
        get: function () {
            return this.newX;
        },
        set: function (val) {
            this.newX = val;
            alert("X has a value of " + this.newX);
        },
    }
});
```

ES6 classes are nicer if you can use them:

```
class SubClass extends ParentClass {
    get x() {
        return this.newX;
    }

    set x(val) {
        this.newX = val;
        alert("X has a value of " + this.newX);
    }
}
```

You can also make this sort of helpful function:

```
function extend(target, source) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source).forEach(function (name) {
        var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, name);
        Object.defineProperty(target, name, descriptor);
    });
}
```

and use it like so:

```
extend(SubClass.prototype, {
    get x() {
        return this.newX;
    },
    set x(val) {
        this.newX = val;
        alert("X has a value of " + this.newX);
    },
});
```